# print all the column values after exact match of variables in file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, sh

I have a file list.txt containing data like this

```
hvar-mp-log.hvams europe@gmail.com asia@gmail.com aust@gmail.com
mvar-mp-log.mvams japan@gmail.com ant@gmail.com
mst-mp-log.mst  korea@gmail.com maxwell@gmil.com antra@gamil.com
pif-mp-log-pif atlas@gmail.com  korea@gamil.com japan@gmail.com mexco@gmail.com
```

I need to match the string in the list.txt and print the matched string column data.

If string=mst-mp-log.mst print korea@gmail.com maxwell@gmil.com antra@gamil.com

I can match string=mst-mp-log.mst like this example gives me only second column info like korea@gmail.com

```
string="mst-mp-log.mst"
awk -v var="$string" '$1 == var {print $2}' list.txt
```

how to print matched string all the mail id's. expected output should be like
korea@gmail.com maxwell@gmil.com antra@gamil.com

Answer (score 3):

```
$ awk -v tgt='mst-mp-log.mst' '$1==tgt{$1=""; $0=$0; $1=$1; print}' file
korea@gmail.com maxwell@gmil.com antra@gamil.com
```

Explanation:

- `$1==tgt` - obvious
- `$1=""` - sets the original $1 to null and reconstructs $0 but $1 is still a field (just with null value now) so it still exists in the record and so there is a blank (OFS) placed between $1 and $2, just like between all of the fields.
- `$0=$0` - re-splits the record into new field numbers so the original $1 is removed and $2 becomes the new $1 but doesn't change the actual string making up the record so the blank still exists at the start of it
- `$1=$1` - forces $0 to be reconstructed from its fields and so removes the leading blank
- `print` - obvious

Here you can see step-by-step what's happening to the record and the fields:

```
awk -v tgt='mst-mp-log.mst' '$1==tgt {
    printf "\nRecord original:\n<%s>\n", $0 ; for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) printf "\tField %d/%d [%s]\n", i, NF, $i

    $1=""
    printf "\nRecord after $1=\"\":\n<%s>\n", $0 ; for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) printf "\tField %d/%d [%s]\n", i, NF, $i

    $0=$0
    printf "\nRecord after $0=$0:\n<%s>\n", $0 ; for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) printf "\tField %d/%d [%s]\n", i, NF, $i

    $1=$1
    printf "\nRecord after $1=$1:\n<%s>\n", $0 ; for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) printf "\tField %d/%d [%s]\n", i, NF, $i
    print ""

    print
}' file
```

```
Record original:
<mst-mp-log.mst  korea@gmail.com maxwell@gmil.com antra@gamil.com>
        Field 1/4 [mst-mp-log.mst]
        Field 2/4 [korea@gmail.com]
        Field 3/4 [maxwell@gmil.com]
        Field 4/4 [antra@gamil.com]

Record after $1="":
< korea@gmail.com maxwell@gmil.com antra@gamil.com>
        Field 1/4 []
        Field 2/4 [korea@gmail.com]
        Field 3/4 [maxwell@gmil.com]
        Field 4/4 [antra@gamil.com]

Record after $0=$0:
< korea@gmail.com maxwell@gmil.com antra@gamil.com>
        Field 1/3 [korea@gmail.com]
        Field 2/3 [maxwell@gmil.com]
        Field 3/3 [antra@gamil.com]

Record after $1=$1:
<korea@gmail.com maxwell@gmil.com antra@gamil.com>
        Field 1/3 [korea@gmail.com]
        Field 2/3 [maxwell@gmil.com]
        Field 3/3 [antra@gamil.com]

korea@gmail.com maxwell@gmil.com antra@gamil.com
```

Comment: Thank you Ed Morton for detail explanation  with solution.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution without using awk

```
# Capture the search output into bash array
array=( $(grep "$string" list.txt) )

# First column (Index-0) is your search string, remaining are the email IDs, so print array elements starting from Index 1
echo ${array[@]:1}
korea@gmail.com maxwell@gmil.com antra@gamil.com

# Print all array elements separated by space
echo ${array[@]}
mst-mp-log.mst korea@gmail.com maxwell@gmil.com antra@gamil.com

# Find number of elements in array
echo ${#array[@]}
4

# Advantage with this solution is that you can iterate over the array using a for loop:
for str in "${array[@]}"; do
   echo $str
done
mst-mp-log.mst
korea@gmail.com
maxwell@gmil.com
antra@gamil.com
```

This may need slight adjustment if file structure changes